# QGIS Pre-set CRS/projections missing/unavailable

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS 2.0.1 running off of a Ubuntu computer.

I have been going through some basic tutorials (http://fossgeo.org/free-qgis-courses/) and have come up against a small and silly little obstacle. Some of the problems and examples involved in these tutorials require specific CRS presets. When I first started working, my copy of QGIS had all of the different CRS types that came up. However, after a few days something appears to have happened and I no longer have access to a bunch of the CRS types referenced in the tutorials. I have tried looking them up by name and EPSG# to no avail. I have tried reinstalling the program.

I have not been able to find a download or plugin to restore all of the CRS presets, does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a broken installation.

QGIS stores CRS information in a spatialite database `srs.db`. During installation, it synchronizes this database with CRS information from GDAL using a tool named `crssync`.

On Ubuntu, you find the files in `/usr/share/qgis/resources` and `/usr/lib/qgis`. You might need admin priviliges to change or run them.

QGIS for Windows standalone has the files in `C:\Programs\<QGIS version>\apps\qgis\resources` and `C:\Programs\<QGIS version>\apps`.

It might help to rerun crssync, or re-install GDAL and QGIS to get the database back.